# How to group objects in different sized groups by their similarity score

Tags: clustering

Complete noob at this topic, so bear with me. I have a collection of objects and I can calculate similarity scores between each pair of objects. I've gone ahead and created a "similarity matrix" that contains all similarity scores between all pairs of objects.

What I'd like to do now is to find how I could organize these objects in groups. I need to be able to specify how big/small these groups should be and then the objects should be grouped accordingly.

I'm a software engineer not a data scientist, so I'd appreciate it if someone would give me some pointers on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you can use the similarity matrix you created, but a typical data science solution for this problem would to use kmeans clustering or hierarchical clustering, depending on if you want to select the number of groups or the size of the groups. If you prefer equally sized clusters, here is a related post with some ideas you can try:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452576/k-means-algorithm-variation-with-equal-cluster-size